# Order confirmation mail sent before the Payment

Tags: kentico

Need help to understand the Kentico email notification flow on check-out process.
I used the PaymantForm webpart, on click of "Paynow" button, order confirmation email sent to customer before the payment step completes.
How to restrict this and how to send the order confirmation mail only after the payment is done.

Payment Gateway: Paypal

Kentico Version: 10

Please suggest.

Thanks,
Sharath

Answer (score 2):

This email you're talking about is simply stating the order was created, no completed.  You can look into the E-commerce module and check out the overall e-commerce settings.  In there you can define your order statuses.  With each order status, you can define if an email is sent or not.  I'd suggest starting there.

Comment: Thanks Brenden for the inputs. My understanding about the e-commerce that, order should create only after user initiated the Payment process. In this case user just redirected to payment gateway (PayPal), and user gets the order email. User may cancel the payment and redirect back to site, in that case it doesn't make any sense of the email sent. Thanks for the suggestion, I will look into the E-commerce module.

Comment: You're correct @Sharath.  You can maintain the sending of the emails based on the status of the order.  The order NEEDS to be created before it is sent off for payment.  Once the order succeeds, fails or is cancelled (order status), the email will be sent depending on the stauts of the order when it changes.

Comment: Thanks Brenden for all clarifications.